# How to fix Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING in Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

In my application i want use **Retrofit** for get some data from server.
I write below codes but when run application and call api show me below **error :**

```
E/socketLogResponse: Err : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Please see my above codes and help me

**API response from server :**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "time": 0.014972925186157227
}
```

**ApiService interface :**

```
@POST("api/log")
    Call<SocketPingResponse> getSocketPingLog(@Header("jwt") String jwt, @Body SocketPingBodySendData socketPingBodySendData);
```

**SocketPingResponse class :**

```
public class SocketPingResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    private Double time;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Double getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Double time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

**SocketPingBodySendData class :**

```
public class SocketPingBodySendData {
    @SerializedName("auction_id")
    @Expose
    int auction_id;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    List<SocketPingEntity> data;

    public int getAuction_id() {
        return auction_id;
    }

    public void setAuction_id(int auction_id) {
        this.auction_id = auction_id;
    }

    public List<SocketPingEntity> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<SocketPingEntity> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Api call codes in activity :**

```
pingEntityList.addAll(socketPingDatabase.socketPingDao().getSocketPingEntityList());
                        SocketPingBodySendData pingBodySendData = new SocketPingBodySendData();
                        pingBodySendData.setAuction_id(auctionID);
                        pingBodySendData.setData(pingEntityList);
                        Toast.makeText(context, ""+pingEntityList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Call<SocketPingResponse> pingResponseCall = apis.getSocketPingLog(jwtToken, pingBodySendData);
                        pingResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<SocketPingResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<SocketPingResponse> call, Response<SocketPingResponse> response) {
                                    if (response.body() != null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, response.body().getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        if (response.body().getStatus().equals("ok")) {
                                            pingEntityList.clear();
                                            socketPingDatabase.socketPingDao().deleteAll();
                                        }
                                    }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<SocketPingResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.e("socketLogResponse", "Err : " + t.toString());
                            }
                        });
```

**ApiClient class :**

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = Constants.SERVER;
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static Context context;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.interceptors().add(interceptor);
        client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("X-Client-Version", Constants.getAppVersionName()).build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("uuid", Constants.getUUID(Constants.currentActivity)).build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("agent", Constants.getAgent()).build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient client2 = client
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(client2)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: what you get in response is not what you expect. You expect to get JSONObject, but you get something else, some string.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, as it is likely the server problem, or misunderstanding between your app and the server. Nobody knows what your backend expects from you, and what it gives as result.

Comment: I think you have to specify that the content-type is json. Moreover, not related to your problem but it's an advice : don't add multiple interceptor just to add new header. You can add them in one interceptor

Comment: I don't see where you specify that you've sending JSON... try to add `@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")` above the signature of the method

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem returns string when no data is returned. Backend can usually do such errors. this error had happened to me before. you should check the response json when no data is available

Comment: i checked in postman and show show me below response : {"status":"ok","time":0.0363459587097168}

Comment: can you check there is no data in response case  with the postman and write here ?

Comment: when not send data to postman show me below {
    "status": "error",
    "time": 0.01767897605895996
}

Comment: You misunderstood me . you have tried not to send any data, but I mean getting no data.

Comment: yes my friend, i getting no data and show me above error message in postman

Comment: this is the problem . when you getting no data in response you must get empty object not String. your json response must look like : {
    "status": "",
    "time": 0.00
}

Comment: when i send empty object, when show me above resposne message

Comment: don't send empty object. this problem needs to be restored in the web service. web service should send you empty object instead of string

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is typesafe library. It means that it waits only particular (predefined) types of objects. If server sends something else - it crashes with error. This is your case. Just check raw server response and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: i checked in postman and show show me below response : {"status":"ok","time":0.0363459587097168}

Comment: @Jungle postmans answer is not relevant in this case as post shows only raw response. To see error response in app check "if (response.body() != null) {" line with breakpoint and evaluate servers answer with response.errorBody() and it will show you actual servers answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your API call

from

```
@POST("api/log")
Call<SocketPingResponse> getSocketPingLog(@Header("jwt") String jwt, @Body SocketPingBodySendData socketPingBodySendData);
```

to

```
@POST("api/log")
Call<String> getSocketPingLog(@Header("jwt") String jwt, @Body SocketPingBodySendData socketPingBodySendData);


pingEntityList.addAll(socketPingDatabase.socketPingDao().getSocketPingEntityList());
                        SocketPingBodySendData pingBodySendData = new SocketPingBodySendData();
                        pingBodySendData.setAuction_id(auctionID);
                        pingBodySendData.setData(pingEntityList);
                        Toast.makeText(context, ""+pingEntityList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Call<String> pingResponseCall = apis.getSocketPingLog(jwtToken, pingBodySendData);
                        pingResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                                    if (response.body() != null) {
                                        //Convert here your string response to Other POJO format
                                    }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.e("socketLogResponse", "Err : " + t.toString());
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: when use your code show me below message on response in logcat. i use this code in **onResponse**`Log.e("socketLogResponse", "Response : " + response.body());` but show me below message on logcat : `Response : <!DOCTYPE` .   how can i fix it?